# How do I pass 'user_id' to CustomerSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I don't know how to pass `user_id` from `requests.user.id` and use it in the `CustomerSerializer` to save the object to the database. The error stems from the fact that `user_id` exists in the customer table in the database but it does not show up as a field to be passed in the rest_framework API frontend (only `phone` and `profile_image` do).

**Here is the Customer model:**

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Here is the ViewSet:**

```py
class CustomerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

    # Only admin users can make requests other than 'GET'
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return [permissions.AllowAny()]
        return [permissions.IsAdminUser()]

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET', 'PUT'])
    def me(self, request):
        customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user_id=request.user.id)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        elif request.method == 'PUT':
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

... **and here is the Serializer:**

````py
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'profile_image', 'phone']
```python


... and when I try to save a new customer by sending a POST request to the endpoint with the following data:

```json
{
    "profile_image": "Images/image.png",
    "phone": "009293930"
}
````

I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /api/customers/
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
Exception Location: /home/caleb/.local/share/virtualenvs/Cribr-svgsjjVF/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py, line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
Python Executable:  /home/caleb/.local/share/virtualenvs/Cribr-svgsjjVF/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/caleb/Desktop/Cribr',
 '/home/caleb/Desktop/Cribr',
 '/snap/pycharm-professional/290/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/caleb/.local/share/virtualenvs/Cribr-svgsjjVF/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/snap/pycharm-professional/290/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Thu, 28 Jul 2022 23:38:53 +0000
```

I figured the issue here is that the serializer class is not getting the `user_id` value from the POST request. I tried passing `request.user.id` to the serializer from the viewset through a context object (i.e., `context={'user_id': request.user.id}`) but I couldn't figure out how to then add it to the validated data which the serializer passes to the `save` method.

Any help on this issue will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `serializer.save(user_id=request.user.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve it by overriding the create method in the serializer. I added the following:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'profile_image', 'phone']
        read_only_fields = ['user_id']

    
    # NEW ---------------------------------
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            customer = Customer.objects.filter(user_id=user)
            if customer.exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'Customer already exists')
            else:
                customer = Customer.objects.create(
                    user=user, **validated_data)
            return customer
```

The object saves fine now.

Comment: note: The self.context['request'] is set by overrding the get_serializer_context in the viewset and returning a dictionary {'request': request}

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using DRF and viewsets is that most of the work has already been done for you. In instances such as this, you usually just need to tweak a few things to get it working the way you want. I've re-written your solution for you below:

```
class CustomerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

    # Only admin users can make requests other than 'GET'
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return [permissions.AllowAny()]
        return [permissions.IsAdminUser()]

    def get_object(self):
        customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user_id=self.request.user.id)
        return customer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def me(self, request):
        return self.retrieve(request)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer_exists = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists()
        if customer_exists:
            return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
          
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

From the DRF docs:

> The ModelViewSet class inherits from GenericAPIView and includes implementations for various actions, by mixing in the behavior of the various mixin classes.
>
> The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are .list(), .retrieve(), .create(), .update(), .partial_update(), and .destroy().

The `ModelViewSet` will also set up a urlconf for you, which, excluding `list` will expect an object pk (primary key) to be provided in the url to allow the view to know what resource in the database you are trying to access. In your case, you want to determine that resource based on the authentication credentials provided in the request. To do this, we can override `get_object` to get or create the customer based on the authenticated user's id.

The next change we make is to define our action for the `GET` method. We want to be able to retrieve a resource, without specifying the pk in the url conf, hence `detail=False`. We can then simply call the builtin `retrieve` function from this action, which in turn will use `get_object` to get and return the customer object.

Thirdly, your `PUT` request will be directed to `update`, which is inherited from `ModelViewSet`, so you don't need to do anything here as you've already overwritten `get_object`.

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)

    if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
        # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
        # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
        instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Lastly, you want to set `user` on your serializer to read only (or just remove it entirely), as this should always be set based on the credentials passed in the request.

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'profile_image', 'phone']
        read_only_fields = ['user_id']
```

A great resource for looking at all the functions that you inherit from DRF classes is https://www.cdrf.co/.

Good luck, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it out and I still got the same error, 'user_id' still isn't getting passed!

Comment: What worked was that when I hit api/customers/me and there is no customer available the it gets created (because of the get_or_create) but when I try to create a customer by sending a POST request to api/customers then it throws the aforementioned error. There should be a way for the user_id to be passed to the database when the post request is being saved.

Comment: @OlusolaCaleb Sorry i misread your question and thought you were making PUT requests. I've updated my answer to better handle POST requests. Take note of the `perform_create` method which demonstrates how to pass kwargs to the serializer when making saves to the database.